# get function value in a plugin

Tags: php, plugin, variable

i'm trying to write my own plugin and new to php
to simplify i want to grab a string from the tempalte then do something with it 
How do i call getMyString() in another function?

EDIT:

```
class test
{

    public $return_data = "";

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->EE =& get_instance();
        $this->return_data =  $this->getMyString();
    }

    public function getMyString() {
        $tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata;
        return "<p>TEST : " . $tagdata . "</p>";
    }

    public function newFuction() {
          $this->return_data = self::getMyString();
    } 
    // usage stuff here

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->return_data = $this->getMyString();
```

return_data should only be used for the construct method (nod to Derek ;).

In the EE template:

```
{exp:test}woo hoo{/exp:test}
```

or

```
{exp:test:getMyString}woo hoo{/exp:test:getMyString}
```

I appreciate this is only a test, but you can't return anything from the construct if you're returning stuff from the methods - because the construct will always get called, therefore always return something, then the method will return something - so you'll get incorrect output.

To debug, simply put:

```
echo "<pre>";var_dump($tagdata);echo "</pre>";
```

...before the return in the getMyString method.

Your comment mentioned this:

```
{exp:test} {exp:test:getMyString}My Pretty string here...{/exp:test:getMyString}
```

The first `{exp:test}` tag shouldn't be there (just checking ;) as that will only output "TEST: " because there is no tagdata and as mentioned, it may mess with the tag pair `{exp:test:getMyString}` because it outputs something.

Comment: Small correction - `$this->return_data` should only be used by your plugin's constructor function (since it can't return a value) - so with `{exp:my_plugin}`. When calling a function within your plugin class (`{exp:my_plugin:my_function}`), always return directly from your function.

Comment: yes but for some reason even with $this->return_data = $this->getMyString(); in the construct it is not returning the value between 
{exp:test}
{exp:test:getMyString}My Pretty string here...{/exp:test:getMyString} the {exp:test} only treturns <p>TEST : </p> from the above code but not the string itself

Comment: Can you update your answer to include the EE code please. I'll update my answer to reflect your new code.